# Why can't I get this webclient to work for this URL?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim wc = New System.Net.WebClient

    Dim apistring = wc.DownloadString("https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarketsummaries")
```

The URL open just fine in browser. Somehow webclient can't get that. Hmmm....

What's the problem?

Update: I used a modified webclient with useragent and cookies and it works. I think it checks for things like user agent but I do not know.

I still do not know what the problem is and still curious. If anyone want to examine and check feel free.

Basically what exactly this site look for, and what software we can use to easily check what the problem is.

Comment: Are there any errors reported at all? It could be the URL is denying access. Maybe throwing a 403 error?

Comment: You can delete the question if it's no longer reproducible and it's of no use to SO.

Comment: @Bugs, or the OP can self-answer with the "making the request look like it comes from a web browser" solution, though I'm sure that there must be a dupe for that by now! =)

Comment: It says that connection is closed unexpectedly. I think knowing why this happens will help me learn what's going on and hence useful for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites will not respond to a plain HTTP Request that contain only the `Host` header. They require additional common headers that typically would be set when being originated in a web browser.

Most commonly when a WebClient request fails the server is looking for the  `User-Agent` or the `Accept` header. The server may rely on these headers to determine how to output the Response to client. A typical example is when an API looks at the `Accept` for `text/html`, `application/xml` or `text/javascript` or `tapplication/json` to determine if it should return HTML, XML, Javascript or JSON.

Depending on the site it might also look for `Referer`, 'Cookie', `Accept-Language` and/or `Accept-Encoding` headers.

Trying a combination of those values based on what your browser produces.

For this particular website, the browser sends:

[image]

The header this site is looking for is the `User-Agent` header. If it is not present it closes the connection and returns no response.

Comment: how did you know that? What software you use?

Comment: It comes from experience. I just began with a basic web client with all of the headers shown in the screen shot and removed them one by one until I could reproduce the error, then submitted only with that header to confirm it was the root cause.